# Moving cgi script from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 results in a 403 error

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf, cgi

My configuration is as follows:

```
#Include for LinuxStat (http://lstat.sf.net)
Alias /lstat/ "/usr/local/lstat/www/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lstat/www/">
#for execute CGI files
Options ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
</Directory>
```

It always shows error 403 on Apache 2.4, while on Apache 2.2 it was working fine.

What should be corrected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it myself ;)

```
#Include for LinuxStat (http://lstat.sf.net)
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Alias "/lstat/" "/usr/local/lstat/www/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lstat/www/">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI
Require all granted
Allow from all
```